# How to add css class in aspx.cs page means code behind page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

In aspx page I am using following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCreateCustRepoUsers">
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="cst_checkbox_container1" id="cs1" runat="server">
        <div class="cst_checkbox unselected">
          <label class="checkbox_value">
          <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRead" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkRead_CheckChanged" /></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </asp:GridView>
```

in code behind I am using:

```
 cs1.Attributes.Add("class", "some-class");
```

But its giving error that `cs1` does not exits in current context.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: please note, when formatting your code, I had to remove an extra `</` between the `</asp:TemplateField>` and `</asp:GridView>`.  I presume this was a typo when putting the code into SO.  If not you need to update your code to reflect this change.

Comment: Ya, its correct that i am simply pasting the code from my working solution and its very difficult to format the code here, so its may possible to miss any extra code. So plz provide something which do formating easily..

Comment: If you're asking for something to format code easily on SO, then that is not a tool that SO provides (that I'm aware of) - there are too many languages and standards.  Otherwise you really need make sure your code is written in a good way - so both you and others will easily understand the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cs1` will not be directly available to the page, because it will be repeated for each and every item in the `DataSource` for your `grdCreateCustRepoUsers` `GridView`.

What you need to do is set it as part of the `RowDataBound` event of the `GridView`.

Using the [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) in C#

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)e.FindControl("cst_checkbox_container1");
     div.Attributes["class"] = "some_class";
  }
}
```

Here it is in VB.NET (which I wrote initially, because I didn't notice you had `aspx.cs` in the title)

```
Sub grdCreateCustRepoUsers_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdCreateCustRepoUsers.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim div as HtmlGenericControl = e.FindControl("cst_checkbox_container1")
    div.Attributes("class") = "some-class"
  End If
End Sub
```

(Note, I have very limited experience of the `GridView` control, but this is based on my experience of the similar `<asp:Repeater>` control. The above code is therefore untested, but hopefully points you in the correct direction.)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlContainerControl div = e.Row.FindControl("cs1") as HtmlContainerControl;
        div.Attributes["class"] = "some_class";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

syntax:

```
controlName.CssClass="CSS Class Name";
```

Example:

```
txtBank.CssClass = "csError";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Kishor. It seems you are signing your answers with your name, job description and an additional link. These have been removed. [Signing your content is not encouraged on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Adding the link you have might see them flagged as spam. Just a heads up that you might want to avoid that in the future. You can add such information to your profile if you wish. Hope that helps. Have a nice stay on SO. ;)